# Ubuntu 20.10 aarch64 (Raspberry Pi CM4) how do I access 1-Wire devices?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, 1-wire

Running Ubuntu 20.10 aarch64 (Raspberry Pi) on a Compute module 4 Am scratching my head on how do I access 1-Wire devices?

I've tested the DS18B20 sensor using Raspberry Pi OS and it works by enabling the device and I can then poll the thermometer in the `/sys/bus/w1/devices/<deviceid>/temperature`.

I've made the same changes to the `/boot/fireware/config.txt`; but, I see no indication that the kernel nor do I see any obvious kernel modules to load that would enable Raspberry Pi 1-Wire support.

Anyone know if it's supported and how to access it?

Comment: `I've made the same changes to the /boot/fireware/config.txt` - what "changes" did you make? the kernel modules would be `w1_gpio`, `wire` and `cn` by the way

Comment: When running RPIOS All I did was add..
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin-4 to /boot/config.txt and after a reboot I could access the temperature via /sys/bus/w1/devices/<device>/tempreture

Let me recheck with the module names you've managed..

Comment: OK I can see from the kernel headers that w1-gpio is in there I'l just installed the kernel source and if I can enable or find the kernel  modules.

Comment: It appears the the w1-gpio, w1-therm and wire are in the generic kernel not the raspi
I've not managed to build the kernel the instructions on line don't work.   But at least I know that the drivers are available I just have not been able to build them.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the the w1-gpio, w1-therm and wire are in the generic kernel not the raspi I've not managed to build the kernel the instructions on line don't work. But at least I know that the drivers are available I just have not been able to build them.

I've recently downloaded and tried the 21.04 release candidate and that fully supports raspi One-Wire devices.

So that confirms that 20.10 doesn't support w1 and that its fixed in 21.04